# Where do I have to put Google Analytics code and Event Tracking code, in order for them both to work correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, google-analytics, tracking

1)
My Google Analytics tracking code is placed in the HEAD,
the Event tracking code is placed BEFORE BODY END TAG.

In this version, the clicks are tracked correctly, but the link leads to an /undefined page.

2)
When I put both scripts in the HEAD, the links work, but no events are tracked.

**QUESTION)
What is the correct way to implement both codes?**

INFO)
This is my Google Analytics tracking code

`<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'xxxx.xx']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>`

This is my Google Event tracking code

```
<script>
$( '#lp-pom-image-xxx' ).click( function(event) {

event.preventDefault();
var buttonLink = $(this).attr("href");

var callbackFunction = function(){
window.location = buttonLink;
}

if(window._gat){
_gaq.push(['_set','hitCallback',callbackFunction]);
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'x', 'y', 'z']);
} else {
callbackFunction(); 
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why the first one is not working.

The second one is not working because your script is not inside a dom ready handler, so when your event registration code is executed the target elements are not loaded in the dom, this results in the handlers not getting added to the target elements.

So add the script in a dom ready handler

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#lp-pom-image-xxx').click(function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        var buttonLink = $(this).attr("href");

        var callbackFunction = function () {
            window.location = buttonLink;
        }

        if (window._gat) {
            _gaq.push(['_set', 'hitCallback', callbackFunction]);
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'x', 'y', 'z']);
        } else {
            callbackFunction();
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: jQuery(function ($) {...}) ---- is this the dom ready handler I should place around the event tracking codes?

Comment: added this, now neither link nor tracking works ...

<script>
jQuery(function ($) {


$( '#lp-pom-image-199' ).click( function(event) {

 
event.preventDefault();

 
var buttonLink = $(this).attr("href");

 
if (typeof ga != 'function') { 

window.location = buttonLink;

}
 
ga('send', 'event', 'download', 'click', 'dl_lite2', {

'hitCallback' : function () {

window.location = buttonLink;

} 
});
});
  })
</script>

Comment: also whether jQuery library is included before this script

Comment: jquery 1.4.2 library is included

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49611/discussion-between-user387184-and-arun-p-johny)